# SecurityError When Ember Application Deployed to Multiple Buckets

Tags: ember.js, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have my `index.html` document deployed to a `www.lorem.io` bucket and the rest of my assets deployed to a `cdn.lorem.io` bucket. Both of these buckets have their own Cloudfront distributions. When visiting https://www.lorem.io/ I'm receiving the following error:

> Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'https://cdn.lorem.io/' cannot be created in a document with origin 'https://www.lorem.io' and URL 'https://www.lorem.io/'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're ember.js configuration file defines `rootURL` to be `"https://cdn.lorem.io"` which is wrong. When accessing lorem.io your `rootURL` is supposed to be `"https://www.lorem.io"`.

Perhaps you meant `baseURL`. See [this explanation](https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/d1aff13969-the-difference-between-rooturl-and-baseurl) for the difference between `rootURL` and `baseURL`.

Warning: Keep in mind, that `baseURL` [gets deprecated](http://emberjs.com/blog/2016/04/28/baseURL.html) in ember-cli 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

Our `locationType` setting in our configuration file is `hash` in production.

In ember.js configuration file, can you change your locationType as `hash`, and try again:

```
ENV.locationType = 'hash';
```

[From Guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.6.0/configuring-ember/specifying-url-type/)

[From a discussion on github](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/3112)

Comment: I'd really like to keep using `history` for my `locationType`